# Regular expression not behaving the way expected

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression applied here - http://regex101.com/r/dT6dN8/9 - that doesn't act the way I expected.  I want to turn 390.140747070313px into 390px but for some reason my pattern of `\..*px` is going way beyond the 'px' after ..0313.    Does anyone understand what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replace `390.140747070313px` with `390px`, this will do:

Simply replace `(\d+)\.\d+px` with `$1px`.

Your original regex `\..*px` is wrong because the `*` quantifier is greedy and you apply it to `.`. But the non-greedy version will work just fine: `\..*?px`. But the version I suggested above is more correct though, as it will only ever replace numbers.